# In Excel, can I sum a column of cells based on whether or not a given value is in each of the rows?

Tags: excel, array-formulas, sumifs, sumproduct

Within Excel, is there an array formula or something else that could shorten the formula below? This is only an example going through 12 rows. The actual formula would have thousands of rows, which is why I'd like to find a way to write this formula much shorter. I've considered and tried SUMIF and SUMPRODUCT in addition to what's below, but I haven't found a way for it to check for a specified value in multiple columns, and then doing that for many rows, like a FOR loop would do. The below formula is in Cell J3. I have attached an image of the spreadsheet example.

[image: Spreadsheet]

```
=SUM(
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B3:$E3,0)),$F3,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B4:$E4,0)),$F4,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B5:$E5,0)),$F5,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B6:$E6,0)),$F6,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B7:$E7,0)),$F7,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B8:$E8,0)),$F8,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B9:$E9,0)),$F9,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B10:$E10,0)),$F10,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B11:$E11,0)),$F11,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B12:$E12,0)),$F12,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B13:$E13,0)),$F13,0),
IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($I$3,$B14:$E14,0)),$F14,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($F$3:$F$14*(MMULT(N($B$3:$E$14=I3),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($B$3:$E$14)^0))>0))
```

This is an array formula and it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Looks perfect Scott. Thank you. I haven't seen MMULT or TRANSPOSE mentioned in any of the other threads I was trying to find this solution in. That being said, I get a VALUE! error if I try to use your formula. What do you think could be the issue? Should it have anything to do with the version of Excel? I only have Excel 2013 at work.

Comment: You get that on your full data or on the test data?

Comment: On the test data that I shared. I'm still running queries to get the spreadsheet of the full data.

Comment: Make sure the number are not text that looks like numbers. Not sure why else it works for me and not you.

Comment: I verified to ensure they were numbers. And your recreation looks spot on, which I appreciate, so I'll keep tweaking it and working on it to see what's not right. Thanks again. I'm not great with multiplying matrices and I need to be, so you got me thinking in the right direction if nothing else.

Comment: had you checked that there is actually "Bill" and not "Bill " (with space) ?

Comment: Since it used SUMPRODUCT, and I didn't see the curly brackets, I didn't realize it was an array formula. CSE fixed the problem. My bad.

Comment: @STEMboy2020 yes, sorry.  In my version, one no longer needs to use CSE and sometimes I too assume it is not needed on older versions.  I will fix.

Answer (score 0):

**Improved solution**

```
=SUMPRODUCT($F$3:$F$14,CEILING(((($B$3:$B$14=$I3)+($C$3:$C$14=$I3)+($D$3:$D$14=$I3)+($E$3:$E$14=$I3))/4),1))
```

Idea : 4 is the number of rows/week. Use ceiling() to normalize value instead of int() n sqrt().

Expansion note : just add another row condition & adjust 4 to the number of rows.

---

**Past solution (for reference)**

```
=SUMPRODUCT($F$3:$F$14,INT(SQRT(INT(SQRT(($B$3:$B$14=$I3)+($C$3:$C$14=$I3)+($D$3:$D$14=$I3)))+($E$3:$E$14=$I3))))
```

should do.

idea : while $B$3:$B$14=$I3 part is creating an array of 0 n 1, the INT() n SQRT() function 'force' the '+' sum to become 1 even if there is more than 1 match in the same month.

please share if it works/not. (:

p/s : (note for expansion) Upon dissecting the int() and sqrt() function, you can see that sqrt(3)=1.73205 , sqrt(2)1.414213, sqrt(1)=1 and its int() results the same value (1) . So let say you want to add more rows, just use 'bundle' 3 rows together in one int(sqrt(__)) function, recursively.

Comment: This also works. And since it did not require TRANSPOSE, CSE was not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the kind verification. I had added some notes for expansion for future reference. /(^_^)

Comment: Yeah, at first glance I couldn't tell what you were doing, but then I figured it out. It's very creative, and would work until you added a 16th column, which is when another set of INT(SQRT()) would need to be added. I like it, and I shouldn't have that many columns, even in my future project.

Comment: I've already added the improved formula.. no need for int/sqrt, just change the rows number from 4 to 16 plus add other rows conditions.